# Different databases or tables sets for each user

Tags: mysql, database, large-data-volumes, large-data

I'll have to create database(s) to store very large amounts of data but being able to extract data fast enough using MySQL. 
I was wondering if it will help if I create a new database or a new tables set for each user instead of using a single large database.
The only worry I have is that the users will be many but I hope that they will not use the project at the same time.
Does anyone have any experience with similar structures or any other advice to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use single database & single "User" table for all users...allocate theme unique id....
or if a single user have many datas.....
Example

if user_a have 10 books....

make a different table like "Book_table" with this structure.....

id , user_id , book_name

you can use this structure for multiple users......

Please explain more what user's details you have......i will try to give more accurate answer.....

Comment: The database will be normalized no mater if I use single database or multiple databases. The problem is that there are three tables that contains sendings of messages sent to subscribers, each visit generated from this messages and openings of the messages. This tables will gain between 60M and 120M records per year if they contain the data for this events for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use only one User table. If you need to search that table quickly you can index columns that you need fast searching on. For examplel you have a user table with first_name, last_name and email address. These are text fields so searching would be slow since it needs to scan the entire table and compare all the strings (note string comparison is much slower than integers). To get around this you can index columns like email address which is sort of like an ordered table (hidden away) which only has emails in it. Ordered tables are much easier to search so your searches would be fast.

Here is a good basic [example](http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases) of how to use indexing. Be careful with indexes though since they add overhead on your inserts. Some reading up on your part will really help here.

Anyway that is a really over simplified explanation of indexing.